# Am I applying the Inclusion Exclusion principle correctly?

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

Q: Find how many integers $n$ satisfying $ 1\le n \le 5000$ are divisible by at least one of the numbers 4, 7 and 33.

I've done the following:

$$|A| = \lfloor 5000/4 \rfloor = 1,250 $$
$$|B| = \lfloor 5000/7 \rfloor = 714 $$
$$|C| = \lfloor 5000/33 \rfloor = 151 $$

$$|A\cap B| = \lfloor 5000/(4 * 7) \rfloor = 178$$
$$|A\cap C| = \lfloor 5000/(4 * 33) \rfloor = 37$$
$$|B\cap C| = \lfloor 5000/(7 * 33) \rfloor = 21$$
$$|A \cap B\cap C| = \lfloor 5000/(4 * 7 * 33) \rfloor = 5$$

Next I do this:

$$|A|+|B|+|C| - |A\cap B| - |A\cap C| - |B\cap C| + |A \cap B\cap C|$$

Which works out as:

$$1,250 + 714 + 151 - 178 - 37 - 21 + 5 = 1,884$$

Answer = 1,884.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you made any calculation errors, that's absolutely right!

Comment: Great! thanks!!